# How to use Hive in Firebase background method (FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-hive

I'm trying to add support for background push notifications to my flutter app, but I catched error message :(

Here is my code:

```
void startApp() {
  ...
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onFirebaseBackgroundMessage);
  ...
  runApp(MyApp());
}


Future<void> onFirebaseBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  
  // init() is called 'Hive.initFlutter();'
  final hiveDb = HiveDb();
  hiveDb.init();

  hiveDb.saveMessage(message);
}
```

Error message:

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

I read that Hive doesn't support multithreading, but is there really no solution? Help